# Uniformly apply image positions in powerpoint

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I have a single image per slide in a 50 slide powerpoint project. I want to uniformly assign all of the images' position to a desired XY location. What's a quick way of doing this? Manually going to each image's properties and entering their values takes too long.

Comment: Write a macro. Depending on your level of expertise that may or may not be quicker than doing it manually.

Answer (score 1):

The free version of my PPTools StarterSet add-in includes a tool that lets you size/position an image or other shape once, "memorize" its size/position, then apply the memorized size/position to any other selected shape/s with one click.

http://www.pptools.com/starterset/

Another of my add-ins, ShapeStyles, lets you memorize/apply position/size independently and also gives you the ability to memorize/apply lots of other properties. The free demo lets you memorize up to five styles at any one time, so it might suit your needs as well.  The demo never times out, and if five styles is all you need, it's effectively free.

http://www.pptools.com/shapestyles/

Answer (score 0):

2007, 2010
Right Click on the image:

- select size and position.
- select position tab.
- Format horizontal and vertical positions on slide.

in 2013, Right click on the image, select format image. A toolbar appears on the right. Select position sub-tab.